# Codeshare and TSA Pre

Tags: usa, tsa-precheck

I have a Known Traveler Number through Global Entry, and normally get TSA Pre on my boarding passes for US airports.

British Airways is the only airline flying non-stop between my home airport, San Diego, and London. In the past, I've booked directly with them. BA does not participate in TSA Precheck.

The flight is codeshare with several airlines, including AA, which does participate in TSA Precheck. Could I get TSA Precheck by booking through AA using their codeshare flight number?

Comment: Note that as of May 2018 [BA officially joins TSA PreCheck®](https://londonairtravel.com/2018/05/17/british-airways-tsa-precheck/)

Comment: @PeterM Yes. My last trip to England was on BA, and I got precheck. Although the problem no longer exists for the case in the question, I think it, and its answers, are still valid because they may be applicable to other airlines and routes.

Answer (score 2):

When in the airport, which counter are you going to check in at and get your ticket from - BA or AA? If BA, then you are not getting TSA Pre. If AA, then you can ask them.

But, in reality it's much simpler - when you go thru TSA, just  show them your Global Entry card and they will stamp your ticket with red EXPEDITED stamp which essentially will give you the TSA Pre privileges. I've done it successfully a few times in similar situations (flying BA out of Boston was one).

Comment: Isn’t the main advantage of TSA precheck to avoid the huge line for regular travelers? If I read you correctly, you went to the TSA pre side of the line, had the agent stamp EXPEDITED after seeing your global entry card, and then went to the TSA pre security procedures (kept laptop in bag, keep shoes and jacket on).

Comment: Yes, depending on the tsa agent you may get all the tsa pre privileges (or none if he doesn't feel like). I was even able to get into TSA Pre line to get to the agents once, just by flashing my Global Entry card. Your mileage will vary, but my experience has been mostly positive.

Comment: I was behind a person at SFO who attempted to get to the TSA Pre queue with a GE card. The lady guarding the lane looked at his boarding pass and sent him to the long queue instead, so that part is definitely unreliable.

Comment: As I said, your mileage will vary :) I've have mostly good experience flashing my GE card when the ticket didn't have TSA Pre

Comment: Will they give the same consideration to NEXUS users (who have a card very similar to GE users, and their program technically includes GE privileges?

Comment: Hard to say - first, GE privileges are subjective, depending on the mood of the TSA officer :) And second I've never had a NEXUS card, but if it normally gives you TSAPre then an officer would give it the same consideration as he would to a GE card.

Answer (score 0):

There's a possibility that you'd get TSA Pre benefits if you booked the ticket with a codeshare partner that uses TSA Pre and checked in via them.  This has other complications, like seat reservation issues (although some airlines will let you reserve seats on codeshare flights now).

If you bought the ticket directly from British Airways, you don't have a PNR code from American to use their check-in system, so that won't work.

Personally, I've run into enough issues with codeshare bookings that I would just book with BA directly and show up at Lindbergh Airport a few minutes earlier than you'd prefer, to deal with the extra time to clear security.